# Straight hand in Java poker game

Tags: java

I am having trouble finishing the straight method for a poker hand. I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
public static boolean containsStraight(int [] hand)
{
boolean straight = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  if (hand[i] == 2 && hand[i] == 3 && hand[i] == 4 && hand[i] == 5 &&               hand[i] == 6)
  {
    straight = true;
  }
  if (hand[i] == 3 && hand[i] == 4 && hand[i] == 5 && hand[i] == 6 && hand[i] == 7)
  {
    straight = true;
  }
  if (hand[i] == 4 && hand[i] == 5 && hand[i] == 6 && hand[i] == 7 && hand[i] == 8)
  {
    straight = true;
  }
  if (hand[i] == 5 && hand[i] == 6 && hand[i] == 7 && hand[i] == 8 && hand[i] == 9)
  {
    straight = true;
  }
}
return straight;
```

}

Comment: Please define and expand on "doesn't work".

Answer (score 3):

As pL4Gu33 has already stated in his answer, your comparison is faulty. Essentially, each step through the for-loop leaves `hand[i]` at a constant value (say, 4). That means that your if-statements are checking:

```
if(4 == 4 && 4 == 5 && 4 == 6 && 4 == 7 && 4 == 8) {
    ...
}
```

This will *never* evaluate to true. If you knew for certain that you had five elements in the hand and that the hand was already sorted, you *could* do

```
if (hand[0] == 2 && hand[1] == 3 && hand[2] == 4 && hand[3] == 5 && hand[4] == 6) {
    ...
}
```

However, I'm going to show you a better answer.

The first thing you should do is to sort your hand. Once you do that, it's easy to step through the hand and check to see if the next card in the hand is exactly one greater than the previous card. If you get to the end and this holds true, then it's a straight.

```
/*
 * You will need to import java.util.Arrays
 */

public boolean isStraight(int[] hand) {

    if(hand == null || hand.length != 5) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Automatically sort the hand
        Arrays.sort(hand);

        // Set the "previous" variable to a theoretically impossible value
        int prev = -1;

        // Iterate through the hand and see if the next card is exactly one more than
        //    the previous one.
        for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {

            // If prev is -1, then this is the first time through the for-loop
            // If the card that we're on has a value of the previous card + 1,
            //     we still have the possibility of a straight.
            if(prev == -1 || (prev + 1) == hand[i]) {
                prev = hand[i];
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use this for (int i = 0; i < hand.length-1; i++) {
   if(hand[i] != (hand[i+1] - 1)){ return false;} for checking the straight.

Comment: Make up your mind, @pL4Gu33! ;) In seriousness, the main reason why I'm using the 'previous' variable is to make it easier to show. I did take some of your earlier suggestions though!

Answer (score 2):

You say in every iteration hand[i] must be 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5. That is impossible. There is only one number in hand[i].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are using the cycle incorrectly, because you are always checking the value of the same card in `hand[i]`. My suggestion would be either to do a sort first, or if you want to be more efficient, you can use a second field of booleans, that would indicate, whether a card of given value is present in your hand. This way you can easily check, if you have any number of cards in succesion.

```
public static boolean containsStraight(int[] cards) {

    int count = 0;
    boolean[] valueInHand = new boolean[10];

    for (int card : cards) {
        valueInHand[card] = true;
    }

    for (boolean value : valueInHand) {
        if (value == true) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        // works for any number of cards
        if (count == cards.length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```